# TypeScript throwing an error on hook when passed to value of Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I am creating a cart context for a Nextjs ecommerce store. When trying to pass the `setCart` to the value prop of the `CartContext.Provider`, TypeScript throws an error, Ill attach a screenshot below to the error as well as a screenshot of the code. Thanks!

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FngbR.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NCuN.png)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ICart` interface declaration to:

```
import React from 'react'

interface ICart {
  cart: ICartItem[] | null;
  setCart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ICartItem[]>>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the type of setCart in ICart interface to this:

```
setCart : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ICartItem[]>>
```